# Angular 4 - How to display the template of the inheriting class component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display a list of items (components) according to their types:

I have an array of components. 
All inherits from a base class.
The array type is defined as that of the base class.
I want to display the array (let say as a list of items) each with its own template, rather than the base template.

I have tried that:

In the app.component.html:

```
<app-shape *ngFor="let shape of shapes"></app-shape>
```

In the app.component.ts:

```
shapes: ShapeComponent[] = [new CircleComponent(), new SquareComponent()];
```

I have defined 3 Components:

```
export class ShapeComponent {
}

export class CircleComponent extends ShapeComponent{
}

export class SquareComponent extends ShapeComponent{
}
```

And the result is that I get a list of shapes.

Does Angular support such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Declarative approach

You can use [`ngComponentOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet).

Code:

```
shapes: ShapeComponent[] = [CircleComponent, SquareComponent];
```

template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let shape of shapes">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="shape">
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

> **ngComponentOutlet** - Instantiates a single Component type and inserts
>   its Host View into current View. **NgComponentOutlet** provides a
>   declarative approach for dynamic component creation.
>
> **NgComponentOutlet** requires a component type, if a falsy value is set
>   the view will clear and any existing component will get destroyed.

So, no hard code needed in template. ***ngFor** will iterate over component types array in your code

**Update**

Don't remember add dynamic rendering component to `entryComponents` of **AppModule**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, AComponent, BComponent ],
  entryComponents: [
    AComponent, BComponent 
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-compoent-outlet)

### Imperative approach with setting data

**app-component.template:**

```
<ng-container #comps>

</ng-container>
```

Get access to `#comps`(ng-container) view by `ViewChild` decorator and create components.
So you can't initilize component like `b = new BComponent()`.

1. First need to resolve component factory.
2. Initialize component via [viewContainerRef's](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#description) [createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent) method. It returns [reference](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) to instantiated component
3. By the reference, get access to instance property and update any data as you need

**app-component.ts:**

```
 @ViewChild('comps', { read: ViewContainerRef }) comps: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.comps.clear();
    let aComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.compArr[0]);
    let aComponentRef = this.comps.createComponent(aComponentFactory);
    (<AComponent>aComponentRef.instance).name = 'A name';

    let bComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.compArr[1]);

    let bComponentRef = this.comps.createComponent(bComponentFactory);
    (<BComponent>bComponentRef.instance).name = 'B name';
  }
```

[StackBlitzh Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-load)

Comment: Doe's not work, I get: "[Angular] Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *"

Comment: Thanks @Yerkon, it worked. Although since I have array of instances, not array of types, I just needed to add a method getType(ShapeComponent) that returned the inheriting type and set it to the ngComponentOutlet. Furthermore, I got an exception when I have created a constructor with a parameter, saying that the base class cannot be instantiated. I removed it (sadly..) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Sorry @Yerkon, I have just realized that there is a problem with this solution, new instances are being created instead of using my instances from the 'shapes' array and this misses the point completely. I am losing all my data :|. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Eibi,  `new instances are being created instead of using my instances` Right. Creating component by `new Component()` doesn't mean that component is creating in angular. If you want to create component and pass data to them. I recommend you to use **imperative** approach https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components

Comment: How to access `ViewContainerRef` from inherited class? Since decorators do not inherit, I have problem here (Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined): `@ViewChild('licenceContent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) protected licenceContent: ViewContainerRef;` is a declaration in base class, error at `loadLicenceComponent() { this.licenceContent.clear();...` in inherited component class. Markup is SHARED by inherited classes - this is where #licenceContent is needed. Calling `loadLicenceContent` from `ngAfterViewInit` of the inherited class - but it does not matter, since the problem is decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Each component must have separate selector.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-shape" //maybe even is not needed here
})
class Shape {

}

@Component({
  selector: "app-rect"
})
class Rect extends Shape {

}
```

So you can do something like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let shape of shapes">
  <app-rect *ngIf="//check if shape is rect"></app-rect>
  <app-circle *ngIf="//check if shape is circle"></app-circle>
</div>
```

Comment: I do indeed have separate selectors. But I would rather not to add code each time I am adding a new type. I am basically looking for the equivalent of DataTemplate in WPF which knows to select the inherited class DataTemplate without using extra code that explicitly does it.