# multiple path for load same module - lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have multiple components in one module. I want to show the components based on routing path.
 for http://localhost:4200/account I  want to show account component.
for http://localhost:4200/setting I  want to show settings component ..etc

app.routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: './modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
},
{
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren:'./modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule', 
},
```

settings.routing.module.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'account',
        component: accountComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'account/edit',
        component: accountEditComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'settings',
        component: settingsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'settings/edit',
        component: settingsEditComponent
    }
];
```

what changes I do in  settings.routing.module.ts to show those components.

Comment: There is no sense in what you're trying to do. Why are your not making each route as a different lazy loaded module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really want to do this you can use [*UrlMatcher*](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) to find the correct component.

SIDE NOTE:I wouldn't recommend you to do this. instead go with my other answer. I think it's a better approach. BUT of-course it's your decision.

[Simple demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-lazy-loading-module-multi-route-2-1-module-matcher)

**app.routing.module.ts** (not changed)

```
{
    path: 'settings/account',
    loadChildren: './modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
},
{
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren:'./modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule', 
}
```

**settings.routing.module.ts**

```
export function isAccount(url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup) {
  return group.segments.length === 1 && group.segments[0].path.endsWith('account') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}

export function isSettings(url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup) {
  return group.segments.length === 1 && group.segments[0].path.endsWith('settings') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'account',
        component: accountComponent,
        matcher: isAccount
    },
    {
        path: 'account/edit',
        component: accountEditComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'settings',
        component: settingsComponent,
        matcher: isSettings
    },
    {
        path: 'settings/edit',
        component: settingsEditComponent
    }
];
```

Result is exactly what you're looking for:

http://localhost:4200/settings will show settings component.

http://localhost:4200/account will show account component.

Comment: This should be build into Angular without this hack... shorter urls with lazy-loading is better!

Comment: put the functions to return UrlMatchResult. More clear.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have `settings` as the default path (component) for this module, and all other components as a child route.

[Simple DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-lazy-loading-module-multi-route-2-1-module)

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'settings/account',
    loadChildren: './modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
},
{
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren:'./modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule', 
},
```

**settings.routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: settingsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'edit',
        component: settingsEditComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'account',
        component: accountComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'account/edit',
        component: accountEditComponent
    }
];
```

http://localhost:4200/setting will show settings component.

http://localhost:4200/settings/account will show account component.

..etc

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

settings-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PubliclistsComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '', redirectTo: 'all', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'all', component: ChallengelistComponent},
          {path: 'me', component: ChallengelistComponent}
        ]
    }
];

const settingsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '', redirectTo: 'participants', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'bleh', component: TeamlistComponent},
          {path: 'bleh-bleh', component: TeamlistComponent}
        ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AccountsRoutingModule { }


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SettingsRoutingModule { }
```

settings.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AccountModule { }


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class SettingsModule { }
```

app-routing.ts

```
{
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: './modules/settings/settings.module#AccountsModule',
},
{
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren:'./modules/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule', 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [**benshabatnoam**'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57092811/271450) above, you could create a **universal matcher function** like so in your module:

```js
// load components from root path
export function isPath(url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) {
  let r = '';
  for (const p of group.segments) {
    if (p !== group.segments[0]) {
      r += '/';
    }
    r += p.path;
  }
  return r === route.data!.path
    ? ({ consumed: url })
    : null;
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { component: SettingsComponent, matcher: isPath, data: { 'path': 'settings' } },
  { component: AccountComponent, matcher: isPath, data: { 'path': 'account' } },
{ component: AccountComponent, matcher: isPath, data: { 'path': 'full/path' } }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to create two lazy modules that share a third non-lazy module.