# Lazy load same module from different paths

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have following `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
  {
    path: 'discover',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/platform/user-profile/platform.module').then(m => m.PlatformModule)
  },
  {
    path: ':userRoute',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/platform/user-profile/platform.module').then(m => m.PlatformModule)
  },
```

My goal is that **/discover** should open DiscoverPageComponent from PlatformModule

**/userName1** should open UserPageComponent from PlatformModule

My `platform-routing.module.ts` contains following:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'discover',
    component: DiscoverPageComponent,
  },
```

This doesn't work as /discover will always open the UserProfileComponent instead of the DiscoverPageComponent. I can only open the DiscoverPageComponent from /userName1/discover

How can I have those two different routes open their specific component from the same lazy loaded module?

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3rc5g
Please see /discover and /anyUserName1

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: partial fix - in platform-routing.module.ts replace `UserProfileComponent ` with `DiscoverPageComponent ` and `DiscoverPageComponent ` with `UserProfileComponent `.

now `/discover` with open `DiscoverPageComponent `

Comment: I would suggest u use something like a platform-container.component.ts with a router-outlet. then u define at the ' ' path your container and define also ```children: [  { path: ' ', component: UserProfileComponent }, { path: 'DiscoverPageComponent ', component: DiscoverPageComponent },  ] ``` this setup will work.

Comment: @piyushjain now anything opens the DiscoverPageComponent but nothing opens the UserPageComponent :)

Comment: @MikeS.  I have added a stackblitz

Comment: If you're lazy-loading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66468311/271450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below sample code, do changes in your routing modules

In app-routing.moudle.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./platform/platform.module').then(m => m.PlatformModule)
  },
];
```

In platform-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "user",
    children: [
      {
        path: ":user",
        component: UserProfileComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "discover",
    component: DiscoverComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "discover",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];
```

1. http://localhost:4200/discover
2. http://localhost:4200/user/1

Comment: I also suggest naming the user route something like `user/:user` instead of just `:user`.

Comment: I can not change the user route. instagram.com/example just looks better than instagram.com/user/example